# Term for a permutation group every element of which except of identity has no fixed points

Tags: group-theory, permutations, terminology

A *permutation group* on a set $D$ is a group whose elements are functions on $D$ and whose composition is function composition.

Is there a term for a permutation group every element of which except of identity has no fixed points?

Comment: Is composition even going to be an operation on such things?  Seems rare that it would be closed.

Comment: @Randall Consider the action of a group on itself by left multiplication

Comment: @Randall I don't quite understand your English. Reformulate. Do you mean some "closed" (what do you mean?) group or do you want to close my question? A typical example of a group conforming to my definition is the group of translations of a Euclidean space.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen good call.

Comment: Perhaps not the group, but its [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Types_of_actions) on $D$ is called *free* or *semi-regular* or *fixed point free*

Comment: Those elements are called derangements. But I don't know for a term for the analogous group.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think a more common  meaning of a fixed point free action is one in which no element of the set is fixed by the whole group. Actions in which no non-identity element has fixed points are also called free actions, particularly in geometric group theory.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a *semi-regular permutation group*.

From [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Permutation_group#:%7E:text=A%20permutation%20group%20is%20called,the%20group%20is%20also%20transitive.)

> Permutation group

> A permutation group is called semi-regular (or freely acting) if the stabilizer of each point is the identity group and regular (or simply transitive) if the group is also transitive